# No matching function to call to std::vector<float>

Tags: c++, vector

I am writing a code for 3D world to 2D projection and as i try to push back coordinates in my vectors it gives me this error that there is no matching function to call to std::vector.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include "draw.h"
#include "points.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>



void draw(Display* d, Window w, GC gc)
{
    std::vector<float> xpoints;
    xpoints.push_back (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0);

    std::vector<float> ypoints;
    ypoints.push_back (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0);

    std::vector<float> zpoints;
    zpoints.push_back (-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0);

    for (;;)
    {

        XClearWindow(d, w);

        for (unsigned int c = 0; c < xpoints.size(); c++)
        {
            XDrawLine(d, w, gc, xpoints.at(c), ypoints.at(c), xpoints.at(c+1), ypoints.at(c+1));
        }
        XFlush(d);
        usleep(16666);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see where you're including the vector header? add `#include <vector>`

Comment: Also if you have errors you should include them in your question and the line it occurs

Comment: Please don't sign your questions. Also, read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot push multiple values at once using `push_back`:

```
xpoints.push_back (-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
```

If you are using `c++11` you should directly initialize your vector:

```
std::vector<float> xpoints{-1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the vector header:

```
#include <vector>
```

Comment: Oh my bad i didn't put it in, but i ran that code before in another .cpp file where it did have the #include <vector> header so i already knew that wasn't the problem, but thanks for pointing it to me.